# Java StringIndexOutOfBounds Exception in Server 2008 r2 environment

Tags: java, windows, string, 32bit-64bit

Here is a very simple chunk of code using a jre 1.6 run time environment and running in a 64 bit server Server 2008 R2:
    ....

```
        cntr = 0;
       while (cntr < localheaders.size()) {
                    String tempText = textstring.toUpperCase();
        int pos = 0;
        int lastindx = 0;
        int lendPos;
        int tendPos = 0;
        while ((pos > -1) && (tempText.length() > 0)) {
            int headerLengthbeforeUpper = localheaders.get(cntr).header.length();
            String aHeader = localheaders.get(cntr).header.toUpperCase(); 
            int headerLengthafterUpper = aHeader.length();                                                              
            pos = tempText.indexOf(aHeader);  
            // 10_21_2010
            if (pos > 0) { // ef 07-10-2011
                char c;
                try {
                    c = tempText.charAt(pos - 1);
                    if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(c))
                        pos = -1;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Value of pos->" + pos);
                    System.out.println("Length of the string->"
                            + tempText.length());
                                            System.out.println("header length before->"+headerLengthbeforeUpper);
                    System.out.println("header length after->"+headerLengthafterUpper);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
........
```

What I am finding is that the statement `pos = tempText.toUpperCase().indexOf(aHeader);` (about 10 lines down)
is being set intermittently to a value in the string `tempText` that is greater than the length of the string.   This results in a `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.   The index is always within 100 of the actual length of the string.   For example, in a test I ran this evening, the `pos` varaible was set to 24432 for a string of length 24404. Header length is the same before and after uppercasing to address one of the comments below.  Note, if I re-run the code on the same file twice in a row, the error does not occur, the second time.

Some additional information:

1. I don't believe its a threading issue since there is only one thread being used.
2. The code runs fine in a 32 bit XP environment.
3. Both pos and tempText are locally defined variables.
4. When I type java -version, I see the following:

> Java version "1.6.0_20"
>   Jav(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode)

The test environment is running in a VMware Workstation.

I believe this is an environment issue, give the strangeness of the error and the fact that it only shows up in my 64 bit test environment.    I'm trying to figure out the source of the problem.    Has anyone, had this kind of error in the past?    Is anyone aware of bugs related to this particular java build that might cause this kind of error?

Any ideas on how to trouble shoot this problem?

Thank you,

Elliott

Comment: What is `localheaders`: field, local var, what it's type?

Comment: Why are you calling `toUpperCase()` multiple times? Aside from anything else, that means that you're not printing the length of the string you've used `indexOf` on. I can't immediately see why that would be a problem, but it would be nice to at least validate that it's *not* the problem. (You could even have a diagnostic check that the size is the same before and after upper-casing.)

Comment: localheaders is a Vector of data structures called Headers. The header field of the Header class is just a String.  The Vector is defined and populated earlier in the method.      I'm not sure why pos looks suspicious.   It is just a simple int.

Comment: I see no connection between the strings `aHeader`/`localheaders...header` and `tempText` in which you try to find `aHeader`. That of course does not readily explain that the index is larger than `aHeader`'s size, unless the `textstring`in line 3 is really `localheaders...header`?

Comment: Just to clarify, the chunk of code is trying to find the position of aHeader in tempText.    What is happening is that the indexOf in line  10 is yielding a value for pos which is larger than then length of tempText.    How can that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this bug maybe related to your problem:

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6942326

Comment: It is indeed a java bug.   Even though the bug referenced in the link above was never verified, it describes exactly what I was experiencing and when I installed the latest 64 bit build (build 1.6.0_34-b04) The program ran to completion without error.   Thank you, Elliott